# C++ overriding virtual templated method

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I am trying to override a virtual function in C++. After I override the function, it does not actually override it and thus makes the class abstract. 
The code below will give you a good understanding of the problem.

As you can see below, the code works fine for non-pointer templates like an int but fails with an int pointer.

I thought that maybe since it was a problem with references to pointers, I took out the & in the implementation of Derived2 but that did not fix it.

```
template<class T>
class Base {
    virtual void doSomething(const T& t) = 0;
};
class Derived1: public Base<int>{
    void doSomething(const int& t) {
    } // works perfectly
};
class Derived2: public Base<int*>{ 
    void doSomething(const int*& t) { 
    }
// apparently parent class function doSomething is still unimplemented, making Derived2 abstract???
};

int main(){
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2; // does not compile, "variable type 'Derived2' is an abstract class"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for the parameter type `const T&`, `const` is qualified on `T` itself, then when `T` is a pointer like `int *`, the `const` should be qualified on the pointer itself (i.e. `int* const`), not the pointee (i.e. `const int*`).

The correct type should be

```
void doSomething(int* const & t)
```

BTW: You can use the keyword [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to confirm whether the `virtual` function is overrided correctly.

BTW2: Change the style for `const T&` to `T const&` might make it more clear.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jEg9GmZXc6S6VLqw)

Comment: Oh, okay this makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Just to clarify: int a = 3; const int* p1 = &b; int* const p2= &b. In this case, p1's type implies that the data value of a be constant whereas p2 implies that the pointer p2 be constant. Is this correct?

Comment: @akarshkumar0101 Yes, it's correct. In other words, you can't do `*p = 42;` and `p2 = nullptr` but can `p = nullptr;` and `*p2 = 42;`.